# Calculate the difference between two dates in PHP?

Tags: php, date

I want calculate the difference between two dates in Javascript.
Result should be X years, Y months, Z days

I run below code in PHP but result is different. Which is problem in here?

PHP CODE 1

```
// Declare and define two dates 
$date1 = strtotime("2010-04-01");  
$date2 = strtotime("2019-06-30");  

// Formulate the Difference between two dates 
$diff = abs($date2 - $date1);  


// To get the year divide the resultant date into 
// total seconds in a year (365*60*60*24) 
$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));  


// To get the month, subtract it with years and 
// divide the resultant date into 
// total seconds in a month (30*60*60*24) 
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) 
                               / (30*60*60*24));  


// To get the day, subtract it with years and  
// months and divide the resultant date into 
// total seconds in a days (60*60*24) 
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 -  
             $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24)); 


// To get the hour, subtract it with years,  
// months & seconds and divide the resultant 
// date into total seconds in a hours (60*60) 
$hours = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24  
       - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24) 
                                   / (60*60));  


// To get the minutes, subtract it with years, 
// months, seconds and hours and divide the  
// resultant date into total seconds i.e. 60 
$minutes = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24  
         - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24  
                          - $hours*60*60)/ 60);  


// To get the minutes, subtract it with years, 
// months, seconds, hours and minutes  
$seconds = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24  
         - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24 
                - $hours*60*60 - $minutes*60));  

// Print the result 
printf("%d years, %d months, %d days, %d hours, "
     . "%d minutes, %d seconds", $years, $months, 
             $days, $hours, $minutes, $seconds);  
?>
```

Result is 9 years, 3 months, 2 days

HOWEVER. if I run below code, Result is 9 years, 2 months, 29days

PHP CODE 2

```
//差を求める日時の変数を作成
$dateTime1 = '2010-04-01';
$dateTime2 = '2019-06-30';

//DateTimeクラスで2つの日時のオブジェクトを作成
$objDatetime1 = new DateTime($dateTime1);
$objDatetime2 = new DateTime($dateTime2);

//diff()メソッドで2つの日時のオブジェクトから
//ふたつの日付の差をあらわす DateInterval オブジェクトを生成する
$objInterval = $objDatetime1->diff($objDatetime2);

//$objInterval（DateInterval オブジェクト）をformat()メソッドで日時を出力
//%Rは + や - の符号を出力するオプションです
echo $objInterval->format('%R%Y').'year<br/>'; //年
echo $objInterval->format('%R%M').'month<br/>'; //月
echo $objInterval->format('%R%D').'day<br/>'; //日
?>
```

9 years, 3 months, 2 days and 9 years, 2 months, 29days

what is correct?

Comment: `9 years, 2 months, 29days` is correct ... just by looking at it - date differences are hard to calculate because calendars are not simple

Comment: In your first code you're assuming that a month has 30 days. This is not correct and so your first code underestimates the number of days.

Comment: Thanks you. I want Calculate the difference between two dates in Javascript. result shoule be 9 years, 2 months, 29days. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A date difference by itself can only be precise to the **Day**. If you go up to the **months** and **years**, then the results will be inevitably false without a date reference.

You can say

> 9 years, 2 months, 29days till X date

and the reference would be today.

If you take the same period(Year, month, day), and use the date **2019-03-01** as reference, you would have the wrong result.

Here is an example:

```
$objDatetimeSource1 = new DateTime('2010-04-01');
$objDatetimeSource2 = new DateTime('2019-06-30');
$interval =  $objDatetimeSource1->diff($objDatetimeSource2);

$objDatetime1 = new DateTime('2020-02-28');
$objDatetime2 = new DateTime('2020-03-01');
```

`$objDatetime1->add($interval);` will give `2029-05-27 00:00:00` and

`$objDatetime1->add($interval);` will give `2029-05-30 00:00:00` with **3 days** difference between them, when, from the dates `2020-02-28` and `2020-03-01`, you can clearly see that there is **only 2 days** difference.